# how to fetch only ids and comments from the database and the return type should be List<Map<Integer, String>>

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpql

```
@Query("select new map( ques_res.id , qbe.comment ) " +
            "from SurveyResponseAnswerComments qbe " +
            "left join SurveyQuestionnaireResponse ques_res on qbe.queResponseId = ques_res.id " +
            "where ques_res.questionnaireId = :questionnaireId " +
            "and ques_res.inviteeId = :employeeId " +
            "and qbe.tenant.id = :tenantId " +
            "and ques_res.id IN (:responseIds)")
    List<Map<Integer, String>> getCommentsBasedOnQuestionnaireIdEmployeeIdAndResponseIdListMap(
            @Param("questionnaireId") Integer questionnaireId,
            @Param("employeeId") Integer employeeId,
            @Param("responseIds") List<Integer> responseIds,
            @Param("tenantId") Integer tenantId);
```

the above query returns a list of map, where each map contains two sub maps where first sub map has key -> "0" and value -> ques_res.id and second sub map contains key -> "1" and value -> qbe.comment, but all i want is the query to return a list of maps where each map contains only one key-value pair, key should be ques_res.id and value should be comment

note: i have tried the below jpql queries as well but still dint fetch the expected result

Comment: Sorry, but a method name...

Comment: You probably need to annotate the query as native.